# where is the Django's migration listing (migrate -l)

Tags: python, django

I've just upgraded to Django 1.11.4
and I cannot use `python manage.py migrate -l`

There is not listing option any more. Why? What is the replacement for?

That listing was nice way to verify what is not migrated yet.

---

From latest Django:

```
usage: manage.py migrate [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS]
                         [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback] [--no-color]
                         [--noinput] [--database DATABASE] [--fake]
                         [--fake-initial] [--run-syncdb]
                         [app_label] [migration_name]

Updates database schema. Manages both apps with migrations and those without.

positional arguments:
  app_label             App label of an application to synchronize the state.
  migration_name        Database state will be brought to the state after that
                        migration. Use the name "zero" to unapply all
                        migrations.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -v {0,1,2,3}, --verbosity {0,1,2,3}
                        Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
                        2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output
  --settings SETTINGS   The Python path to a settings module, e.g.
                        "myproject.settings.main". If this isn't provided, the
                        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable will be
                        used.
  --pythonpath PYTHONPATH
                        A directory to add to the Python path, e.g.
                        "/home/djangoprojects/myproject".
  --traceback           Raise on CommandError exceptions
  --no-color            Don't colorize the command output.
  --noinput, --no-input
                        Tells Django to NOT prompt the user for input of any
                        kind.
  --database DATABASE   Nominates a database to synchronize. Defaults to the
                        "default" database.
  --fake                Mark migrations as run without actually running them.
  --fake-initial        Detect if tables already exist and fake-apply initial
                        migrations if so. Make sure that the current database
                        schema matches your initial migration before using
                        this flag. Django will only check for an existing
                        table name.
  --run-syncdb          Creates tables for apps without migrations
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django 1.8 introduced `showmigrations` command, which you can use instead ([details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#showmigrations)).

`migrate --list` was deprecated since 1.8 and was removed in 1.10.